# Bevel around object in svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I need to draw a `rect` around an element in svg. I tried to use `getBBox` method for this but if I increase `stroke-width` of an element it becomes larger than rect.
How can I make the rect to contain full object?

Here is an example:

```js
var line = $("line").get(0);
var rect = $("rect").get(0);
var bb = line.getBBox();
rect.setAttribute("x", bb.x);
rect.setAttribute("y", bb.x);
rect.setAttribute("width", bb.width);
rect.setAttribute("height", bb.height);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="200">
  <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="450" y2="150" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="40" />
  <rect stroke="#2795EE" stroke-dasharray="10, 5" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: getBoundingClientRect may include the stroke, it certainly does on Firefox.

Comment: I tested the getBoundingClientRect() function in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. I got three different results. In Chrome, the stroke width was excluded which gave a result that matched the getBBox() function. In Firefox, the stroke width was included which gave the result that Anton wanted. In IE, the stroke width was included but overestimated which gave a result that matched my suggested answer of adding half stroke width to each edge of getBBox() result. Suggesting getBoundingClientRect was a good idea, unfortunately it is very inconsistent across browsers.

Comment: I did some additional testing of the getBoundingClientRect() function in Firefox and IE. I found cases where Firefox returned the desired rectangle but IE returned slightly larger than desired rectangle. I found cases where IE return the desired rectangle but Firefox returned much larger that desired rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

The SVG specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox) states that the getBBox() function "Returns the tight bounding box in current user space (i.e., after application of the ‘transform’ attribute, if any) on the geometry of all contained graphics elements, exclusive of stroking, clipping, masking and filter effects". Basically, the method returns the bounding box of the path points which gives a good bounding box for the filled shaped but not a good bounding box for the stroked shape. You could add half a stroke width to each edge to get a better (but not perfect) bounding box for the stroked shape. In your example, you could use something like...

```
var line = $("line").get(0);
var rect = $("rect").get(0);
var bb = line.getBBox();
var strokeWidth = parseFloat(line.getAttribute("stroke-width"));
rect.setAttribute("x", bb.x - strokeWidth / 2);
rect.setAttribute("y", bb.y - strokeWidth / 2);
rect.setAttribute("width", bb.width + strokeWidth);
rect.setAttribute("height", bb.height + strokeWidth);
```

Note that this approach is not perfect. The expanded box can be too big on some sides.

Also note that this approach can be difficult to modify to handle more complex or more general cases.

Comment: It's not very good on any shape where the angle between two adjacent sides is very small.

Comment: The getBBox() function accounts for the raw path but not things like strokes and filters that extend beyond the raw path. As a result, the getBBox() method can be as much as half a stroke width smaller that desired on each side of the box. Expanding the box by half a stroke width on each side ensures that the stroke width is included inside the box but then the box can then be as much as half a stroke width bigger than desired on each side of the box. As I stated in my answer, it is not a perfect solution.

Comment: I'm trying to explain that it can be massively more than half a stroke width bigger. Sure, your answer works for rect, circle and ellipse. Think of a triangle with one very short side and two long sides though. The angle between the long sides will be very small. The amount the stroke will extend may therefore be very large (although the [stroke-miterlimit](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeProperties) might kick if it's not set too big). Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/td0qx29j/)

Comment: Robert: I am sorry. I misunderstood the point you where making in the earlier comment. You are correct. The tip of a mitered join (especially for a small angle that is not limited by stroke-miterlimit attribute) can extent well beyond the half stroke width factor that I used in my answer. In some of those scenarios, my answer would be a very poor solution. I did try to make it clear in my answer that it was not a perfect solution and that it would have problems in more complex or more general cases.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently getBBox is not working the same in each browser. 
Your best bet in my opinion would be to use Raphaël JS 
http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: getBBox does work the same in each browser. What makes you think it doesn't.